# How to move obj from start to end and end to start on single path

Tags: jquery, animation, svg, jquery-animate

I am trying to move obj on open path from start to end and end to start

Here Single path mean there are not other overlapping extra path

in code i have done from start to end but how can i do it from end to start

Help Please

Thank you in advance

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <!-- Draw the outline of the motion path in grey, along with 2 small circles at key points -->
    <path d="M10.635,5.412L50.41,50.187" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" fill="none" id="theMotionPath"/>
       

        <!-- Red circle which will be moved along the motion path. -->
        <circle cx="0" cy="" r="2" fill="red">

        <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
        <animateMotion dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite">
            <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath"/>
        </animateMotion>
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `keyPoints` and `keyTimes` animation attributes.

The values in `keyPoints` are fractional positions along the path from 0 to 1.
The values in `keyTimes` are timing fractions of `dur`.

```
keyPoints="0;  // start
           1;  // end
           0"  // start
keyTimes="0;   // begin time
          0.5; // halfway through duration
          1"   // end time
calcMode="linear" // for chrome
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <!-- Draw the outline of the motion path in grey, along with 2 small circles at key points -->
    <path d="M10.635,5.412L50.41,50.187" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" fill="none" id="theMotionPath"/>
       

        <!-- Red circle which will be moved along the motion path. -->
        <circle cx="0" cy="" r="2" fill="red">

        <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
        <animateMotion dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite" keyPoints="0;1;0" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" calcMode="linear">
            <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath"/>
        </animateMotion>
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Paul , I did it but most important thing is missing which is calcMode="linear". this is for chrome if we do not use it, it will not working in chrome as per my knowledge.

Thank you one again.

Comment: Yes. The default value for `calcMode` is `paced`. But unfortunately Chrome does not support paced mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the path to end with the original start point.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <!-- Draw the outline of the motion path in grey, along with 2 small circles at key points -->
    <path d="M10.635,5.412 L50.41,50.187 L10.635,5.412" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" fill="none" id="theMotionPath"/>
       

        <!-- Red circle which will be moved along the motion path. -->
        <circle cx="0" cy="" r="2" fill="red">

        <!-- Define the motion path animation -->
        <animateMotion dur="6s" repeatCount="indefinite">
            <mpath xlink:href="#theMotionPath"/>
        </animateMotion>
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: I cant use Multiple overlapping path, is it possible to do same thing with single path??

Comment: we don't need to set path from end to start which is overlapping, you can add just "Z" after my path and its working same. check this : https://jsfiddle.net/6ver8fc6/

Comment: `Z` means close the path, it is the same as what I've done.

Comment: Yes but when its dynamic path its more easy to add Z after path instead of you did m i right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. If the path is a simple line, using `Z` is more easier.